# Using constraints to center an item between two elements

Tags: ios, objective-c, constraints

I tried, in interface builder, to position an image between a button and the bottom of the view, and have stay centered in different screen sizes. I could not find a way to do this, so I've tried to accomplish that using the code below, but it's not working. I can get it centered using explicit points, but if use >= it hugs the bottom and all the space is added between the image and button.

```
NSDictionary *viewsDictionary = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(image, button);
NSArray *constraintsArray = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:[button]->=1-[image]->=1-|" options:NSLayoutFormatAlignAllCenterX metrics:nil views:viewsDictionary];

for (int i = 0; i<constraintsArray.count; i++) {
    [self.view addConstraint:constraintsArray[i]];
}
```

[image: bottom hugging]

How can I get it to center?

Comment: The right way to solve this is to use a spacer view and vertically align your item to that view. This procedure is described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17688299/centering-view-between-neighbors-using-autolayout-in-ios

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you can't use the >= like that, but it can be done easily in IB. Just give the image view a spacing constraint to the bottom of the superview, and a vertical spacing constraint to the button -- edit one or the other of these to have the same value as the other. Give the image view a fixed height and width constraint, and make sure that the button has no other vertical constraints (delete it/them if it does).