# Auto Layout centering view in remaining space (programmatically)

Tags: ios, iphone, autolayout

How can add Auto Layout constraints **programmatically** to center a view in the remaining space (see example picture below)?

[image]

For the moment, I add a container view at the bottom and I then center the view in the container view, but I was wondering if there was any other solution without needing to use a container view.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You need to add a spacer view to do this.

Let's start with some views:

[image: some views]

I'll set up the pink view to take up the top 70% of the root view.  First I pin it to all four edges of the root view:

[image: pink constraints]

Then I'll edit the bottom constraint in two ways.  First, I make sure the first item is the pink view, and second I set the multiplier of 0.7.  Then I update the pink view's frame:

[image: pink constraints adjusted]

Next I'll add the spacer view.  I don't want the spacer view to be visible at runtime, so I'll make it hidden.  Hidden views still participate in layout.  Before setting up constraints, I just put the spacer to the left of the blue view:

[image: spacer added]

Now I'll create constraints to make the spacer stretch from the bottom of the pink view to the bottom of the root view.  The width doesn't matter so I'll just pin it to the left edge of the superview and make it thin:

[image: spacer constraints]

Now I'm ready to set up the blue view.  First I'll give it a fixed size:

[image: blue size constraints]

Second I'll center it horizontally in the root view:

[image: blue horizontal center]

Third I'll pin its vertical center to the spacer's vertical center:

[image: blue vertical center]

That's all the constraints I need.  I'll update all frames to check:

[image: update all frames]

I can test it out using Preview in the assistant editor:

[image: previews]

Notice that the spacer view isn't visible in the preview, but still participates in layout.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer Rob. I am currently using a similar trick (adding a container view that fills the void below view A and then centering view B inside this container view. I was however hoping that there would be any other solution that would not require to add any additional views. I am doing this programmatically (not using interface builder for this particular view controller) so adding helper/container/spacer views just seems to be unnecessary clutter.

Comment: It is necessary if you are using constraints.

Comment: Very well written. Thanks Rob.

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer doesn't address the programmatic alternative (which you emphasized in your question).

There is a programmatic way to do this without having to add additional dummy views to the view hierarchy using `UILayoutGuide` which was introduced in iOS 9.

[The documentation for `UILayoutGuide`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uilayoutguide) is detailed enough.

[This article](https://useyourloaf.com/blog/goodbye-spacer-views-hello-layout-guides/) also add more explanation ([Here](https://github.com/kharrison/CodeExamples/blob/main/AutoLayout/AutoLayout/LayoutGuideController.swift) is the updated code from the article).